# Why doesn't the encoded 'slash' work as expected in restful api?

Tags: rest, flask-restful

I have a restful api request like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4000/sentence=SUITS/Test。
```

And it gives an error in browser:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Then I URL encoded the 'SUITS/Test。':

```
http://0.0.0.0:4000/sentence=SUITS%2FTest
```

This give the same error message.

If I remove the '/' from URL, and it works fine.

Why doesn't URL encoding work here?

This is python restful api with flask_restful.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide "/" before Test it would consider "Test" as a resource and then in this case "sentence" should be considered as query param passed as GET payload after "?" like:

http://0.0.0.0:4000/Test?sentence=SUITS

Comment: the question is then how to get this URL correctly with the '/'?

Comment: I used URL encode with "%2F", but it still says URL not found.